What is the name of this fantasy series about a group of people visiting towns?
I remember a series about a group of people going from town to town. This is a medieval fantasy show, I think there is magic involved.
What only scene I can recall is that they travel to a town where they have a very important (maybe magical) mirror.
These people somehow get involved and brake it and someone says that its 700 years of bad luck or something.
The show was of pretty high budget and filmed nicely.

Please provide more details: How old is this show? Where did it air? Was it in English? Why did these people go from town to town, what did they do? (And by "vising" did you mean "visiting"?)

Can you add more information to this such as an approximate year or decade?  Country of origin? Language?

10th Kingdom maybe? Check out my edited answer below.

Could it be The 10th Kingdom? 

In a hidden realm, fairy tale characters inhabit nine magical kingdoms
  where an Evil Queen plots to rule them. She is trapped in the Fourth
  Kingdom Prison under the rule of Prince Wendell; the spoiled, arrogant
  grandson of Snow White. Weeks before his coronation ceremony, the
  Queen enlists the help of the brutal Troll King and his three children
  to release her before the Prince makes his annual visit to the prison.
Prince Wendell is captured by the Evil Queen, who is his wicked
  stepmother and turns him into a Golden Retriever while her very own
  Retriever is transformed into Wendell. In panic, the transformed
  Prince flees through the Prison and stumbles across a traveling mirror
  in the basement and is transported to New York City. The Troll King
  orders his bumbling children Burly, Blabberwort and Bluebell to bring
  back the escaped Prince while the Queen releases a half-wolf prisoner
  (who is simply called Wolf) to retrieve him instead.
Meanwhile regular Manhattan inhabitants, headstrong waitress Virginia
  Lewis and her oafish father Tony encounter the mishaps caused by the
  new magical arrivals to the city; including Wolf falling helplessly in
  love with Virginia and Tony being given six wishes (which he foolishly
  uses for personal gain and have a tendency to backfire). With Virginia
  having already determined that the transformed Wendell- whom she calls
  'Prince' before learning his identity- is more than a standard dog,
  Tony uses his last wish to wish for the ability to understand the dog,
  who urges them to travel back to The Nine Kingdoms with him to break
  the spell. Tony, feeling responsible for Prince, reluctantly accepts
  and Virginia and Tony are taken back to the realm through the magic
  mirror.
At first, Tony and Virginia are desperate to get home with the magic
  mirror being taken from place to place around the Kingdoms, being
  cleared out of the prison, taken as a prize for a sheep-rearing
  contest, and then sold in an auction. The group travel the lands in
  pursuit of the mirror, facing many dangers and challenges in the
  process, including Virginia's hair being enchanted to an impossible
  length, the Queen's Huntsman, and a conspiracy by the descendants of
  Little Bo Peep to control a town's wishing well. During their journey,
  Wolf questions his loyalty to the Queen in order to gain favour with
  the stubborn Virginia and quickly sides with them. This act prompts
  the Queen to send her relentless and cold-blooded Huntsman to capture
  the Prince along with Virginia and Tony.

Old Answer:
Even though your description is a little vague, I recognized that bad luck part:

>  Dean: *[after surveying the room with all the broken mirrors]* Hey, Sam?  
>  Sam: Yeah?  
>  Dean: This has gotta be like, what, 600 years bad luck?

It's Supernatural! From the episode [Bloody Mary][1], 5th one of the 1st season.


  [1]: http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Bloody_Mary


Definitely not Supernatural. Updated question.

Oh, well then....
